# Adding class to Drupal field via jQuery outputs wrong loop

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, drupal-behaviors

I'm adding a class to a field depending on the contents of that field so I can style each field differently depending on the content. Imagine a burger rating from one to ten...I want to replace the rating with an image for one, another image for two ...and so on.

To do this I need each field class to reflect the field content. Here is the code I'm using:

```
Drupal.behaviors.burgerRating = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
    var burgerRating = $('.field-name-field-rating2').text();
    $('.field-name-field-rating2').addClass(burgerRating);
    }
}
```

This outputs the contents of the field as a class which I can style.
However in a blog View with for example three posts on the page, this code adds all three classes to all three fields when I want each specific field content for each field instance.

What I'm getting is this:

```
<div class="field-name-field-rating2 rating-1 rating-5 rating-8">
<div class="field-name-field-rating2 rating-1 rating-5 rating-8">
<div class="field-name-field-rating2 rating-1 rating-5 rating-8">
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="field-name-field-rating2 rating-1">
<div class="field-name-field-rating2 rating-5">
<div class="field-name-field-rating2 rating-8">
```

I'm thinking I need to get this working with .this() or .each() but I can't get it to work.

Any help? thanks.

Comment: By the way, it is `this`, not `.this()`. About your question: try `$(this).addClass(burgerRating);` or `$(context).addClass(burgerRating);`

Comment: Ah yes...thanks for pointing that out. I tried (this) and (context) ...neither of which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to do that in Javascript ?
You can :

- use a specific template for this field, and do what you want depending of the value of the field
- better, but a bit more complex : create a **field formatter** called "burger_rating", using these hooks :

  - `hook_field_formatter_info` : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7
  - `hook_field_formatter_view` : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7

A **formatter** is the way a field is displayed. It depends of the type of the field (*text*, *number*, *taxonomy_reference*, ...).
If your rating field is a *text* field, you have to create your formatter for a text field.
After creating it, all text fields can use this formatter.

You have to **associate this formatter to your field** on the **display tab** of your content type.

[image]

It's an amazing system, you can add settings form for your formatter as well (`hook_field_formatter_settings_form`)

Comment: Thanks for that. I only opted for the jQuery route as I thought it might be easier. It wasn't and your field template method worked a treat. Thanks again.